# Serializer for status check

Tags: django, validation, serialization

I have a Django project where a restaurant with orders and tables. You can see below the model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ("in_progress", "In_progress"),
        ('completed', 'Completed')
    )
    table = models.ForeignKey(Table, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False, related_name='order_table')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False, related_name='order_user')
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, null=True, max_length=15)
```

I should restrict creating a new order if the table is still in progress. I guess it should be done through serializer but hove no idea about the validation and how to connect request with database information

current serializer (standard):

```
class OrdersModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = "__all__"
```

current view:

```
class OrdersFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = (
            'user', 'table__id', 'status',
        )


class OrdersModelViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrdersModelSerializer
    pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination   
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter)
    filter_class = OrdersFilter
    ordering_fields = ('table', 'user', 'status')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the `queryset=…` of the `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` that excludes `Table`s for which there is an `Order` with `status='in_progress'`:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class OrdersModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    table = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=Table.objects.exclude(order_table__status='in_progress')
    )
    
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).